# array literal: This type can not be coerced to string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals

I have an object

```
const arr = [{ x: 1, y: 2 }];
```

I want to use it in template literals, because of my use case but getting error, Suppose if we log this array using template literal like

```
console.log(`${arr}`);
```

We will get this error

```
array literal: This type can not be coerced to string
```

Any alternative solution that how can I use an array in template literals?

This is my use case I have a query

```
query {
      processes(
        page: 1,
        itemsPerPage: 100,
        filterBy: ${where}, // This is where I am getting this error, I want to pass an array here
      ) {
        id
        businessKey
        name
        processDefinition {
          name
        }
        createDate
        endDate
        tasks {
          id
        }
      }    
    }
```

But it gets converted to `[Object Object]`. I know there are limitations so if you can please suggest a better solution?

This is my where object

```
const where = [{ name: 'endDate', op: 'is null' }];
```

Comment: So, what's `where`?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the code

Comment: Template literals are for strings. If you want an object, why not just assigning ... the object? `filterBy: where`, or if you need to get a copy: `filterBy: [Object.assign({}, where[0])]`...

Comment: Because i need to pass the array in filterBy

Comment: So pass the array? Template literals are for getting strings. So if you need an array, then don't use template literals.

Comment: ok got it but if you please suggest the alternative solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this function

```
const formatArray = (array: Array<Object>) => {
    if (!array || array.length === 0) {
        return '[]';
    }
    const objs = array.map((obj) => {
        return Object.entries(obj)
            .map(([key, value]) => `${key}: "${String(value)}"`)
            .join(', ');
    });
    return `[{${objs.join('},{')}}]`;
};
```

and changed the query to

```
query {
      processes(
        page: 1,
        itemsPerPage: 100,
        filterBy: ${formatArray(where)} // This is where I am formatting my array
      ) {
        id
        businessKey
        name
        processDefinition {
          name
        }
        createDate
        endDate
        tasks {
          id
        }
      }    
    }
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly then what you are looking for is:

```
filterBy: ${JSON.stringify(where)},
```

Comment: it would generate this array [{ "name": "endDate", "op": "is null" }], which I dont want :(

Comment: @sbs  `filterBy: ${JSON.stringify(where[0])},`?